# Derivative of L2 norm

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, derivatives, normed-spaces

I am reading a paper about image processing and I have a question.

In the paper we have equations like below.

$X_{C1} = 0.596X_R - 0.274X_G - 0.322X_B$.

$X_{C2} = 0.211X_R - 0.523X_G + 0.312X_B$

$L = \Vert \Lambda X_{C1} \Vert_2^2 + \Vert \Lambda X_{C2} \Vert_2^2$

And I want to compute $\frac{\partial L}{\partial X_G} $.

I think the answer is 
$$\begin{align*}\frac{\partial L}{\partial X_G} &= \frac{\partial \Vert \Lambda X_{C1} \Vert_2^2}{\partial X_G} + \frac{\Vert \Lambda X_{C2} \Vert_2^2}{\partial X_G} \\ &= \frac{\partial \Vert \Lambda X_{C1} \Vert_2^2}{\partial X_{C1}} \frac{\partial X_{C1}}{\partial X_G} + \frac{\partial \Vert \Lambda X_{C2} \Vert_2^2}{\partial X_{C2}} \frac{\partial X_{C2}}{\partial X_G} \\ & = (2\Lambda^T \Lambda X_{C1})(-0.274) + (2\Lambda^T \Lambda X_{C2})(-0.523) \\ &= \Lambda^T \Lambda(-0.5473X_R+0.6972X_G-0.1499X_B)\end{align*}$$

(Using the identity $\frac{\partial \Vert Q C \Vert_2^2}{\partial C}=\frac{\partial (C^TQ^TQC)}{\partial C}=2Q^TQC$).

But the paper said the answer is $\Lambda^T \Lambda (-0.1536X_R+0.2851X_G-0.1316X_B)$

Am I wrong? Then, how can I compute it?

Comment: I think your calculation is correct. Can you perhaps cite the paper you are referring to?

Comment: The paper is Farsiu, Sina, Michael Elad, and Peyman Milanfar. "Multiframe demosaicing and super-resolution of color images." Image Processing, IEEE Transactions on 15.1 (2006): 141-159. Here is pdf file: http://people.duke.edu/~sf59/TIP_Demosaicing_Final.pdf. The above equations are (13) and (16).